# not extracting meta tags data from my regular expression

Tags: php, regex, meta-tags

I have the following string in a `php variable`

```
<?php
$data="<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<meta name='keywords' content='your, tags'>
<meta name='description' content='150 words'>
<meta name='subject' content='your website's subject'>
<meta name='copyright' content='company name'>
<meta name='language' content='ES'>
<meta name='robots' content='index,follow'>
<meta name='revised' content='Sunday, July 18th, 2010, 5:15 pm'>
<meta name='abstract' content=''>
<meta name='topic' content=''>
<meta name='summary' content=''>
<meta name='Classification' content='Business'>
<meta name='author' content='name, email@hotmail.com'>
<meta name='designer' content=''>
<meta name='reply-to' content='email@hotmail.com'>
<meta name='owner' content=''>
<meta name='url' content='http://www.websiteaddrress.com'>
<meta name='identifier-URL' content='http://www.websiteaddress.com'>
<meta name='directory' content='submission'>
<meta name='pagename' content='jQuery Tools, Tutorials and Resources - O'Reilly Media'>
<meta name='category' content=''>
<meta name='coverage' content='Worldwide'>
<meta name='distribution' content='Global'>
<meta name='rating' content='General'>
<meta name='revisit-after' content='7 days'>
<meta name='subtitle' content='This is my subtitle'>
<meta name='target' content='all'>
<meta name='HandheldFriendly' content='True'>
<meta name='MobileOptimized' content='320'>
<meta name='date' content='Sep. 27, 2010'>
<meta name='search_date' content='2010-09-27'>
<meta name='DC.title' content='Unstoppable Robot Ninja'>
<meta name='ResourceLoaderDynamicStyles' content=''>
<meta name='medium' content='blog'>
<meta name='syndication-source' content='https://mashable.com/2008/12/24/free-brand-monitoring-tools/'>
<meta name='original-source' content='https://mashable.com/2008/12/24/free-brand-monitoring-tools/'>
<meta name='verify-v1' content='dV1r/ZJJdDEI++fKJ6iDEl6o+TMNtSu0kv18ONeqM0I='>
<meta name='y_key' content='1e39c508e0d87750'>
<meta name='pageKey' content='guest-home'>
<meta itemprop='name' content='jQTouch'>
<meta http-equiv='Expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='Pragma' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='Cache-Control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='imagetoolbar' content='no'>
<meta http-equiv='x-dns-prefetch-control' content='off'>";
```

I want to extract the values for the listed meta tags, ***including both name meta tags and httpequiv meta tags***

This is where I'm at with this:

```
// explode the string by newline
$parts=explode("\n",$data);

// loop through each meta tag line
foreach($parts as $part){

  // match inside the name attribute and the content attribute
  preg_match("/<meta name=\"(.*)\" content=\"(.*)\" \/>/i",$part,$matches);

  // returns "</pre><pre>Array()"
  print "<pre>".print_r($matches,true)."</pre>";
}
```

I think there's something wrong with my regular expression.

Comment: Use `DOM` not regex for this

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @jkushner Notice these lines: `<meta name='subject' content='your website's subject'>` and `<meta name='pagename' content='jQuery Tools, Tutorials and Resources - O'Reilly Media'>`  These lines are not valid because the values' apostrophes are not escaped.  Please update your input data, so that I can post a proper DomDocument solution for you.  (p.s. your accepted solution does not accommodate these lines and therefore is not correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The atttributes using single quotes, not double quotes. The closing tag is not `/>` but `>` without space:

```
preg_match("/<meta name='([^']*)' content='([^']*)'\s?\/?>/i", $part, $matches);
```

Explanation :

```
[^']* # get all data until ' is reached
\s?   # with whitespace character (\s), or not (?)
\/?   # with slash (/) or not (?)
```

Here is a version that use also double quotes, and multiple spaces:

```
"/<meta\s*name=['\"]([^']*)['\"]\s*content=['\"]([^']*)['\"]\s?\/?>/i"
```

-> [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/XCbxD3/3)

But, it is always better to use a DOM parser to check HTML elements.

Comment: Thanks alot for the implementation. I agree that using DOM is better but can you explain the parts of the regex pattern for me? Im trying to be more knowledged on regex expressions so understanding this would be valuable to me. Thanks again!

Comment: @jkushner I've updated. Do you need more information?

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, the best / most reliable advice is to parse your html with DomDocument or some other dedicated HTML parsing tool.

This is what a solution implementing DomDocument and Xpath would look like:

Code:

```
$result = [];
$dom=new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);  // do not display warnings on erroneous lines
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->evaluate("//meta[(@name or @http-equiv) and @content]") as $node) {  // target <meta> tags containing both a name & content attribute
    if ($value = $node->getAttribute('name')) {
        $attr = 'name';
    } else {
        $attr = 'http-equiv';
        $value = $node->getAttribute('http-equiv'); 
    }
    $result[]=[$attr => $value, 'content' => $node->getAttribute('content')];
}

var_export($result);
```

However, because you have malformed input data (unescaped single quotes in your content attribute values), these values are truncated at the first single quote.

The most direct workaround to capture the targeted data without truncating these values is to use [a greedy regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/TYsBej/2).

Code:

```
preg_match_all("~<meta (?:name|http-equiv)='(.*)' content='(.*)'>~", $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)
```

This will work your your pattern because your input data has a seemingly strict format.  The targeted lines have exactly the 2 targeted attributes and in the same order with no extra characters to accommodate for.  The greedy `*` quantifier will match zero or more characters (endeavoring to match as many characters as possible -- including apostrophes) while obeying the other pattern requirements.  This pattern will not truncate your attribute values.  I am using `PREG_SET_ORDER` to group your meta tags' data together -- you don't have to use this for your actual project.  Here is a [Demo of the regex method and a commented out DomDocument method that demonstrates the quoting issue](https://3v4l.org/7dQK4).